# IE deselecting RadioButtonList after a javascript function returns false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

We have a RadioButtonList with three ListItems. When the user makes a selection, we want to display a confirm box. If they hit cancel, we just want the selection change to be undone. The below code works fine in everything -BUT- IE 7, 8, and 9. In IE, none of the ListItems are selected after the return false executes, but in all others, with only the code below, the selection is undone and the previously selected item is then selected, like we want. Y U NO WORK IE?

Markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="False">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" onClick="return confirmSubmit(this, event);">Value 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem onClick="return confirmSubmit(this, event);">Value 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem onClick="return confirmSubmit(this, event);">Value 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Javascript:

```
function confirmSubmit(listItem, e) {
    var agree = confirm("Do you really want to change the value?");
    if (!agree) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight forward cross browser compliant way of handling this is with the [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) javascript library.  Here's the solution in using [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) that will work with your code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var rblContainer;
    var lastChecked;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        rblContainer = $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
        lastChecked = rblContainer.children().find('input[checked]'); 
     });
    function confirmSubmit(listItem, e) {
        var l = $(listItem);

        var agree = confirm("Do you really want to change the recipient type?");
        if (!agree) {
            lastChecked.attr("checked", "checked");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            lastChecked = l;
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```